# Sublime text key binding only if find/replace panel is visible

Tags: sublimetext3

I've remapped the "replace_all" to to "super+enter" for making replacements, but I occasionally use this accidentally and I'd prefer to only allow this command if the find/replace panel is visible. Is there a property I can specify in the `args` object which provides this condition?

```
{ "keys": ["super+shift+enter"], "command": "replace_all", "args": {"close_panel": true} }
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can specify a `context` in which the keybinding operates.

For example, adding the following will ensure the keybinding will only be active when the replace panel is open and has the focus:

```
"context": [{"key": "panel", "operand": "replace"}, {"key": "panel_has_focus"}]
```

Your final key binding might look like this:

```
{ "keys": ["super+shift+enter"], "command": "replace_all", "args": {"close_panel": true}, "context": [{"key": "panel", "operand": "replace"}, {"key": "panel_has_focus"}] }
```

Comment: That's awesome, thanks. I wasn't able to find any docs on that property. I changed the key back to "super+enter".